# How to call core C function in R code?

Tags: r, dll

I am trying to call `C` function provided by `R` (default installation) for `HoltWinters` in my own `R` script, but getting message:

```
Error in hw(alpha, beta, gamma) : object 'C_HoltWinters' not found
```

And part of the code in my R script is:

```
 hw <- function(alpha, beta, gamma)
        .C(C_HoltWinters,
           as.double(x),
           lenx,
           as.double(max(min(alpha, 1), 0)),
           as.double(max(min(beta, 1), 0)),
           as.double(max(min(gamma, 1), 0)),
           as.integer(start.time),
           ## no idea why this is so: same as seasonal != "multiplicative"
           as.integer(! + (seasonal == "multiplicative")),
           as.integer(f),
           as.integer(!is.logical(beta) || beta),
           as.integer(!is.logical(gamma) || gamma),

           a = as.double(l.start),
           b = as.double(b.start),
           s = as.double(s.start),

       ## return values
           SSE = as.double(0),
           level = double(len + 1L),
           trend = double(len + 1L),
           seasonal = double(len + f)
           )
```

Based on my preliminary research, it seems we need to use `dyn.load(dllName);`

I have 2 questions now:

```
1) How can I find out `dll` name for this function? 
2) If I run default `HoltWinters.R` we don't need to load `dll`, then why it is required load `dll` in my custom script case?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C_HoltWinters` object is not exported from the `stats` namespace. You can reference it using `stats:::C_HoltWinters`.

Do note that this is against CRAN policy, so it won't be allowed if you put this into a package you plan to submit to CRAN.

Comment: is there a rule for when `:::` is preferred to `::`

Comment: It worked. Thanks! I am trying to understand R implementation of HoltWinters by going over each line and compare it with hand calculated exercise. I am no way positioned to submit any thing. This is for learning purpose.

Comment: @rawr: `:::` accesses unexported objects in a namespace. `::` will only access exported objects.

Comment: Can you help with one more thing? C function is just named as "HoltWinters.C", but in R call we are passing parameter as "C_HoltWinters", how does this work? Thanks!

Comment: @Nambari: See the "Functions that call compiled code" section of the answer to [How can I view the source code for a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/271616).

Comment: I can access holt winters with `stats::` and `stats:::`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Thanks! I didn't fully understand, but as I progress this reference will be useful to get clarity.

Comment: @rawr: `HoltWinters` is exported. `C_HoltWinters` the (`"NativeSymbolInfo"`) object is not.